# Is there a public issue tracker for Chrome separate from Chromium

Tags: google-chrome

I've found a [table rendering bug](https://codepen.io/neil-h/pen/eYvazEe) which affects only Google Chrome, not Chromium or other Chromium based browsers. I've submitted a bug report via `Help > Report an issue` within the Chrome menu, but I'd really like to know the status of it, because it's causing issues for my organization.

So, does anyone know if there's a proper public issue tracker for Google Chrome (not Chromium) where I could see the status of my issue?

---

*Brief description of the bug, just for interest's sake.*

*When you have a table where, based on colspan, one cell should span part of two other cells, instead it will shift to sit fully under one or the other. For example, in the following the "1.5" cell should be half under both the "One" and "Two" cells, but instead Chrome is, at time of writing, rendering it as entirely under the "Two" cell.*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">One</th>
        <th colspan="2">Two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1"></td>
        <td colspan="2">1.5</td>
        <td colspan="1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still report issues affecting Google Chrome at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/wizard even if it doesn't repro in Chromium. Google Chrome is essentially branded Chromium, so most issues that affect Chrome also affect Chromium. Chromium is also where the bug fix would be made, so that's the appropriate place to report.

In the report, it's helpful to provide the versions of both Chrome (repro) and Chromium (no repro) you are using. It may be that the version of Chromium is newer (or older) compared to the version of Chrome. Table rendering in web pages should not differ between Chrome and Chromium, so it likely exists or existed in Chromium as well.